# How to add expand/collapse to mkdocs material theme rightbar?

Tags: javascript, material-ui, material-design, markdown, mkdocs

This is the [Example UI](https://ibb.co/t3W6dmY).

So, the results I want:
Accordion (expand/collapse) blue circled sections, and level 1 (##level1) to be the title and closed all the time when we scroll down or click on, it should expand and get active on whatever line we are.

And when we scroll, it should inactive state as usual, but when we come to the 2nd section, the first stay there and 2nd expands auto and that happens to that too.

Also, I want the content to be shown only for the expanded section when we go at the end, there should be previous and next section title and link. which will lead us to that, but the page should stay the same.

Comment: I think I mixup a little bit, please ask me if you don't get it. I've been searching for a week, but no success, I'm starting to think mkdocs material theme doesn't have that feature or plug in

Answer (score 1):

This is on the roadmap for implementation as part of the brand new Material for MkDocs Insiders: https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/insiders/#prairie-fire